# How to record constants derived by FeatureTools when using Deep Feature Synthesis

Tags: feature-engineering, featuretools

When FeatureTools performs deep feature synthesis, is there a way for it to record constant values it has derived?

For example, I have a with many rows like this:

`| loan_id | loan_term |
|---------|:---------:|
|    a    | 12        |
|   ...   | ...       |
|    z    | 18        |`

DeepFeatureSynthesis engineers `features` including `<Feature: loan_term.COUNT(loan)>` as so:

`|   loan  | loan_term | loan_term.COUNT(loan) |
|---------|:---------:|:---------------------:|
|    a    | 12        | 2000                  |
|   ...   | ...       | ...                   |
|    z    | 18        | 800                   |`

I would like to be able to re-engineer features from a single entity, so that a single loan term of `12` has a `loan_term.COUNT(loan)` of `2000` without having to re-count all of the `loan_term`s in the dataframe.*

I could do this by re-combining the entity with with training data
`ft.calculate_feature_matrix(features, my_entity_set_with_one_new_entity_added)`, but this is inefficient and slow.

Is there a way to direct FeatureTools to record constants found during deep feature synthesis, and to use them for future feature generation?

---

*It's not important to me right now to include the single new loan entity in the calculation. So `12` does not have to become `2001`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a way to do this at this as of Featuretools `v0.3.1`. You can accomplish this manually by doing the following.

1. Using the output feature matrix from running on the training data, select the columns you don't want to recalculate like `loan_term.COUNT(loan)`.
2. Remove the features you selected in 1. from your feature list and running on the new dataset
3. Join the dataframe from step 1 into the dataframe from step 2 on the appropriate key. In this case `loan_term`.

You may have to make some tweaks based on the particulars of your dataset.